# backbone.js correct way to update model when view changed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

What is a correct way to update model when view changed. Is it need to do in a view or in some other place like controller or so?

for example I have a model (model1) and some view (View1) associated with this model. I need to update model when I change some fields on the view. Which is correct way to do that?

Also, I have a collection of that models associated with another view (View2), and i need to put model (model1) to that collection. 
The second question - should View1 or Model1 know about collection, and if yes - how it should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is interesting approach of MVC theory, applied to MVC... Look here for more explaination what is controller in Backbone

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/12/23/backbone-js-is-not-an-mvc-framework/

written by @derick-bailey

In general summary, Bailey says that there are no controllers in Backbone. So, I personally think, that every model updates should take place in the View, associated with that model.

Every model in Backbone, when is added to a collection ( or collections ) and is updated triggers an event in the collection(s) it belongs, so you should listen for that event in your view.

In your example

- View1.collection = [model1];
- View2.collection = [model1, model2, model3];

And when View1 changes model1, then model1 triggers an event to View2.collection, which you can listen.

Comment: but this way some several problems possible. For Example if View subscribed to Model.change and i change the view and after update model, so view will be re rendered once again - which is overkill of course

Comment: That's why it is considered good practice to destroy a View if it's not visible, if this is what you mean.

Comment: @ph0en1x you should never leave viewd around that you aren't using. You'll degrade the performance of your app and can cause zombie events to trigger!

Answer (score 0):

Controllers talk to models, so yes: the correct way to update your model when the view changed is through your controller

Comment: But as i understand controller in backbone is a part of view responsibilities, am i right?